# Disable/Enable random Bonus on Scrabble GridTile

Tags: html, angular, typescript

am trying to add a new feature to a Scrabble project on Angular.
The feature is to swicth the places of the bonus case randomly , when user activate this feature.
my problem is that it's always activated , tried usin boolean or number always same problem .
can someone tell me what am i doing wrong please.

doc.html

```html
<button  (click)="activeRandomBonus()"  class="btn btn-default form-control increaseBtn">Activer BONUS</button>
```

component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-param-game',
  templateUrl: './param-game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./param-game.component.scss'],
})
export class ParamGameComponent {
  timeMax: number = 240;
  timeMin: number = 0;
  gridTile: GridTile;
  console: Console;
  textShow: boolean;

  constructor(
    public paramGameService: ParamGameService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ParamGameComponent>,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  // activeRandomBonus(): void {
  //   this.gridTile.randomButton();
  // }
}
```

grid-tile.ts

```js
export class GridTile {
  arrayOps: ArrayOperations = new ArrayOperations();
  paramGameService: ParamGameService = new ParamGameService();
  letter: string;
  bonusName: string;
  // **test: number;**
  isJoker: boolean = false;
  multiplier: defaults.Multipliers = defaults.Multipliers.NoMultiplier;
  pos: Vec2 = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  };

  gridContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, x: number, y: number) {
    this.letter = '';
    this.gridContext = context;
    this.pos.x = x;
    this.pos.y = y;

    if (this.arrayOps.containsCoordinates(this.pos, defaults.MULTIPLIER_3W)) {
      this.multiplier = 5;
    } else if (this.arrayOps.containsCoordinates(this.pos, defaults.MULTIPLIER_2W)) {
      this.multiplier = 4;
    } else if (this.arrayOps.containsCoordinates(this.pos, defaults.MULTIPLIER_3L)) {
      this.multiplier = 3;
    } else if (this.arrayOps.containsCoordinates(this.pos, defaults.MULTIPLIER_2L)) {
      this.multiplier = 2;
    } else if (this.arrayOps.containsCoordinates(this.pos, defaults.STARTING_TILE)) {
      this.multiplier = 0;
    }
  }
  idOfTile(word1: string, word2: string) {
    this.gridContext.fillText(
      word1,
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 - defaults.TEN,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2,
    );
    this.gridContext.fillText(
      word2,
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 - defaults.EIGHT,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 + defaults.TWELVE,
    );
  }

  randBonusName(x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) {
    if (x === 1 || x === 3) return (this.bonusName = 'Triple');
    else return (this.bonusName = 'Double');
  }

  randomButton(): void {
    this.test = +1;
    // window.location.reload();
  }
  drawTile() {
    // draw empty tile
    this.gridContext.strokeRect(
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE,
      defaults.PLAY_AREA_DEFAULT_WIDTH / defaults.TILES_NUMBER,
      defaults.PLAY_AREA_DEFAULT_HEIGHT / defaults.TILES_NUMBER,
    );

    // Background style depends on multiplier
    this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'white';
    switch (this.multiplier) {
      case defaults.Multipliers.ThreeW: {
        this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'red';
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.TwoW: {
        this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'pink';
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.ThreeL: {
        this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.TwoL: {
        this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'cyan';
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.Center: {
        this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'green';
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.NoMultiplier: {
        this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'white';
        break;
      }
      // No default
    }

    this.gridContext.fillRect(
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + this.gridContext.lineWidth - 1,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + this.gridContext.lineWidth - 1,
      defaults.PLAY_AREA_DEFAULT_WIDTH / defaults.TILES_NUMBER - this.gridContext.lineWidth,
      defaults.PLAY_AREA_DEFAULT_HEIGHT / defaults.TILES_NUMBER - this.gridContext.lineWidth,
    );
    this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    this.gridContext.font = '10px Roboto';

    switch (this.multiplier) {
      case defaults.Multipliers.ThreeW: {
        if (this.test <= 0) this.idOfTile('Mot', 'Triple');
        //desactive random bonus
        else this.idOfTile('Mot', this.randBonusName()); //active random bonus

        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.TwoW: {
        if (this.test <= 0) {
          this.idOfTile('Mot', 'Double');
        } else this.idOfTile('Mot', this.randBonusName());
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.ThreeL: {
        if (this.test === 0) {
          this.idOfTile('Lettre', 'Triple');
        } else this.idOfTile('Lettre', this.randBonusName());
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.TwoL: {
        if (this.test === 0) {
          this.idOfTile('Lettre', 'Double');
        } else this.idOfTile('Lettre', this.randBonusName());
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.Center: {
        this.gridContext.fillText(
          'Start',
          this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 - defaults.TEN,
          this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 + defaults.EIGHT,
        );
        break;
      }
      case defaults.Multipliers.NoMultiplier: {
        // do nothing
        break;
      }
      // No default
    }
  }

  drawLetter(letter: string, isJoker: boolean) {
    if (!this.gridContext) {
      this.letter = letter;
      return;
    }
    this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'peru';
    this.gridContext.fillRect(
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + this.gridContext.lineWidth,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + this.gridContext.lineWidth,
      defaults.PLAY_AREA_DEFAULT_WIDTH / defaults.TILES_NUMBER - this.gridContext.lineWidth - 2,
      defaults.PLAY_AREA_DEFAULT_HEIGHT / defaults.TILES_NUMBER - this.gridContext.lineWidth - 2,
    );

    // draw letter
    this.gridContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    this.gridContext.font = '25px Arial';
    this.gridContext.fillText(
      letter,
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 - defaults.TEN,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE / 2 + defaults.EIGHT,
    );

    const scoreString = isJoker ? '0' : (defaults.LETTER_VALUES.get(letter) ?? 1)?.toString();
    this.isJoker = isJoker;
    // draw letter score
    this.gridContext.font = '15px Arial';
    // TODO: take2 digit scores into account
    this.gridContext.fillText(
      scoreString,
      this.pos.x * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE - defaults.TWELVE,
      this.pos.y * defaults.TILE_SIZE + defaults.TILE_SIZE - defaults.FOUR,
    );
    this.letter = letter; // saving the letter
  }

  get tileLetter(): string {
    return this.letter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are only setting the random feature to on, but when you click the button it doesnt check the current stat. You can do this fairly easily with boolean values by setting them to the opposite of what the currently are.

```js
active = false;
randomButton(): void {
  this.active = !this.active;
}
```

not sure how your code works but you may also need to trigger the class to refresh the logic.

```js
active = false;
randomButton(): void {
  this.active = !this.active;
  this.drawTile();
}
```

Comment: First thing first I have to thank you but the value of the boolean update on the component, interpolatin confirme it but didn't update in the class , I really didn't get it why it dosen't update there, if you can help please do

Comment: what do you mean by 'it didn't update in the class' the grid tile component updates just find when i tested it. The example of main component does not have any references to the grid tile component so i am not sure what you are expecting here. maybe you need to update your question.

Comment: i mean when click event happen in the component activeRandomBonus() boolean value change , but in the grid-tile.ts i need to use the new value in drawTile() function to switch (this.multiplier) { if (active) this.idOfTile('Mot', 'Triple');} 
but there is the main problem value  still like defined on the top active = false;